# How to detect unmatched/mismatched single or double quotes in string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, string

Let's say I have the following function where `userInput` is something a user typed in a `textarea`. How can I detect if `userInput` has mismatched quotes/apostrophes?

Examples (without letters) include: `'"'"` or `'` or `'''`.   (These examples are simplified-  in reality I am expecting there to be letters/numbers between each single/double quote).

```
function example(userInput) {

}
```

Comment: Can we see your tries first?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do it. I thought of an idea for a function, but I realized it wouldn't work.

Comment: What happens when there are backslashes? Eg `'\''`, valid or not?

Comment: take a look at this: https://medium.com/@robhitt/balance-parenthesis-in-javascript-60f451a00c4c

Comment: you may also need to get yourself familiarized with the concept of Stack data structure if you already do not know about that.

Comment: @CertainPerformance your example would be valid. Basically, anything that is valid inside a text editor, like VS Code, (i.e - doesn't lead to a syntax warning), should be fine.